# Can removing high correlations with binary data be used for feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection

I want to remove all my highly correlated features (>0.7) as feature selection process for machine learning. The thing is, that all my data is binary (or a 1 or a 0). I made a correlation matrix (with the `cor()` function in R), which provides me a matrix with all the correlations.

Questions:

1. Can I use correlations, based on binary data (does that make sense?)
2. And if so, can I use it for feature selection for machine learning?

Comment: What correlations? Correlations with other predictors, or with the response? Why feature selection?

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? Say you have 2 features, x6 & x7, w/ r=.71, are you intending to remove x6, x7, flip a coin, remove both, average them to create a new variable, something else?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. With the other predictors. I want to do that because less predictors is better (if they have the same prediction power). So I want to use as less as possible predictors

Comment: How many predictors? How many observations? Alternatives to feature selection like lasso?

Comment: @gung I have 70 predictor features. I want to predict if a person is going to churn Yes or No (binary task). 

For this task I will use a logistic regression, because I want to have clarity on the impact of the different variables.

Comment: OK, let's say that out of your 70 predictor features, you have 2 features, x6 & x7, w/ r=.71, are you intending to remove x6, x7, flip a coin, remove both, average them to create a new variable, something else?

Comment: @gung indeed. Remove one of the predictors (X6 or X7) which is r > 0.7 for example. (see also: https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-the-caret-r-package/)